# Creating the web site https certificate for nginx on local end

Tags: wordpress, nginx, https, ssl-certificate

In order to test should I create https certificate on my local end for the Nginx web server?

The idea is to check how https version of the website works on my local end and to check for the mixed content.

Mixed content is when you have `http://` URLs on `https://` website.
Do I really need to have the self-signed certificate?

Do you have similar experience and how you solved this problem?
Currently, all my websites on local end are `http://`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to have a self-signed certificate or you can use free SSL that letsencrypt provides. Since you are using Nginx, you can read about the directions here: https://www.attosol.com/implementing-ssl-free-quick/

Comment: That would be great, but the problem is letsencrypt work when you have DNS pointing to the URL. In this case, I am on my local laptop.

Comment: Have you tried this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl ??

Comment: Yes, once I understood the SSL certificate is a must I started to use just that.